# Retrieve Magento order comments through API

Tags: rest, magento, soap

**I need to retrieve Magento order comments from another web application.**

The Magento API documentation seems to have two ways to do this, through [REST](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/Resources/Orders/order_comments.html) and [SOAP](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/sales/salesOrder/sales_order.info.html).

The REST documentation is sparse. It only says that the URL structure is like: http://magentohost/api/rest/orders/:orderid/comments

Also, the default REST response is in XML, but I need it in JSON.

I already have an API user set up in Magento and I've created comments from this 'other' web application using SOAP.

**My question, using REST:**

1. How do I get the response in JSON rather than XML?
2. How do I authenticate?

Answer (score 0):

**How to retrive Magento Order Comments with REST Api**

Here is the sample code for REST API Authentication and Retrive Order Comments.

Magento Test File

```
<?php
session_start();
$mageFilename = '../app/Mage.php';

require $mageFilename;  
Mage::app();

// $callbackUrl is a path to your file with OAuth authentication example for the Admin user
$callbackUrl = "http://magentohost/extrafiles/oauth-test.php";
//oAuth Initiate URL
$temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl = "http://magentohost/oauth/initiate?oauth_callback=" . urlencode($callbackUrl);
//oAuth Authorize
$adminAuthorizationUrl = 'http://magentohost/admin/oauth_authorize';
//oAuth Token URL
$accessTokenRequestUrl = 'http://magentohost/oauth/token';
//API Url
$apiUrl = 'http://magentohost/api/rest';

//Consumer Key
$consumerKey = '{{PUT_YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY}}';
//Consumer Secret
$consumerSecret = '{{CONSUMER_SECRET}}';


if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && isset($_SESSION['state']) && $_SESSION['state'] == 1) 
{
    $_SESSION['state'] = 0;
}
try 
{
    $authType = ($_SESSION['state'] == 2) ? OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION : OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI;
    $oauthClient = new OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $authType);
    $oauthClient->enableDebug();

    if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && !$_SESSION['state']) 
    {
        $requestToken = $oauthClient->getRequestToken($temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $requestToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        $_SESSION['state'] = 1;
        header('Location: ' . $adminAuthorizationUrl . '?oauth_token=' . $requestToken['oauth_token']);
        exit;
    } 
    else if ($_SESSION['state'] == 1) 
    {
        $oauthClient->setToken($_GET['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
        $accessToken = $oauthClient->getAccessToken($accessTokenRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['state'] = 2;
        $_SESSION['token'] = $accessToken['oauth_token'];
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $accessToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        header('Location: ' . $callbackUrl);
        exit;
    } 
    else 
    {
        $oauthClient->setToken($_SESSION['token'], $_SESSION['secret']);

       $resourceUrl = "$apiUrl/orders/21833/comments";

       $oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl, array(), 'GET', array('Accept' => '*/*'));
       echo $oauthClient->getLastResponse();
    }
} 
catch (OAuthException $e) 
{
    print_r($e->getMessage());
    echo "<br/>";
    print_r($e->lastResponse);
}

exit;
?>
```

RESPONSE :

```
[
  {
    "created_at": "2016-12-06 15:53:28",
    "comment": "On order, Following Activity is done By: XXX Captured amount of $2,669.97 online. Transaction ID: \"XXXXXXX\".",
    "is_customer_notified": "2",
    "is_visible_on_front": "0",
    "status": "processing"
  },
  {
    "created_at": "2016-12-06 15:53:28",
    "comment": "Order is Created with following : Order is Created By: XXX Grand Total: $2669.97",
    "is_customer_notified": null,
    "is_visible_on_front": "0",
    "status": "processing"
  }
]
```